# Is it possible to not use Redis while using Sidekiq for sending emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq, mailer

I used to use Delayed_Job for sending mails in my rails application but as long as it occupied my ram I decided to use Sidekiq instead. I did this:

**gem file**

```
gem 'sidekiq'
```

**application.rb**

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

**development.rb**

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

**controller**

```
SampleMailer.method(data).deliver_now
```

**mailer**

```
def method(data)
  mail(to: "afsanefadaei@hotmail.com", subject: "#{data}")
end
```

But when I was installing Sidekiq I noticed that I have to install redis-server on my ubuntu. I installed redis server and every thing works fine now but the thing is I don't want to install redis-server . Is redis server a required dependency for Sidekiq or I can ignore it in some way ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: It's "redis", not "radis", btw.

Comment: Yes I made mistake I will edit the question after the right answer. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidekiq uses it as a storage, and it's the only option, it doesn't support other storages. Here's a quote from the documentation:

> Requirements
>
> Sidekiq supports CRuby 2.2.2+ and JRuby 9k.
>
> All Rails releases >= 4.0 are officially supported.
>
> Redis 2.8 or greater is required. 3.0.3+ is recommended for large installations with thousands of worker threads.

[GitHub](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, redis is the storage for sidekiq. So you must use *some* form of redis. If you don't want to install it on your server, you can use one of the many hosted solutions. Just google "redis hosting".